# To choose a set of $n$ rectangles which together form largest number of rectangular layouts

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry

**Question:** Given a number $n$, find that set of $n$ rectangular tiles of any area and perimeter (the tiles in the set could be any type of rectangles; one could choose some of them as identical, some as squares...) which together form the largest possible number of rectangular layouts with different perimeters.
Each of the big rectangular layouts should use all $n$ rectangular tiles in the chosen set and the tiles should be arranged without holes or overlaps. Equivalently, one could try, given a number $m$, to find a set of $n$ rectangular tiles which give exactly $m$ layouts and with $n$ minimal.

**Simple Example:** Let $n =4$. Choosing $4$ unit squares as the tile set, we can form $2$ different rectangular layouts with them - the $2\times 2$ square and the $4\times 1$ rectangle. But, if we choose a set of two $4\times 1$ rectangles and two $2\times 1$ rectangles, we can form $3$ different rectangular layouts - a $12\times 1$, a $4\times 3$ and a $6\times 2$. That is clearly better than the $4$ unit squares.

**Reference:** this problem is attempted on page 5 of [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3472). We could find no final answer: the attempt is based on the theory of Highly Composite Numbers.

**Remark:** This problem can also be viewed as a dissection problem with emphasis on the intermediate pieces - given n, to find a set of n rectangles which can be intermediate pieces in a dissection from R1 to R2 where R1 and R2 are any two elements from a set **R** of rectangles all of different dimensions but same area such that set **R** has maximum cardinality.

**An inside-out version of the question (3rd Feb, 2022):** Given a rectangle and an integer n, to cut the rectangle into m rectangular pieces ( m to be minimized) such that the pieces all together can be reassembled into exactly n different rectangles. For some rectangles and some n, there may be no solution. Allowing some of the m intermediate pieces to be non-rectangles *might not* help in increasing the number of final rectangles.

Comment: Have you tried to look at it from a different angle? Take a number with many divisors and try to cut some of the rectangles with that area into smaller rectangles of the same sizes.

Comment: Highly composite numbers1 are indeed those numbers with many divisors. As is observed in the document linked above, it is often suboptimal to choose a set of n identical rectangles or equal area rectangles. So cutting any given rectangle into equal area rectangles *might not* help...